# can't locate shapefile in basemap Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib-basemap

I put a shapefile "china.shp" in my working directory, I tried many ways to set the path to file for basemap to read it, like

```
m3= Basemap(llcrnrlon=77, llcrnrlat=14, urcrnrlon=140, urcrnrlat=51, projection='lcc', lat_1=33, lat_2=45, lon_0=100)
m3.readshapefile("Y:/Study/Research_Data/geoschem/china",  'china', drawbounds=True)
plt.show()
```

But the error is always `cannot locate Y:/Study/Research_Data/geoschem/china.shx`

Do you have any idea how to set the path, please? Thanks.

Comment: Are u sure your syntax for the filepath is correct ? If its in your working directory `m3.readshapefile("china",  'china', drawbounds=True)` should work just fine

Comment: have your tried `os.path.exists(r "Y:/Study/Research_Data/geoschem/china.shx")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A shapefile usually comes with auxialiary files such as ".shx", ".dbf", ".prj". Here the ".shx" is needed in order to load the corresponding shapefile. 
If you moved the shapefile, you should have moved its auxiliary files to the same location.

Comment: I guess you are right. Previously I only have one .shp file. Just now I downloaded all the files from  the source, then it worked.Thanks!

Comment: @Jeremy If it worked for you, then upvote and accept the answer. Thats how stackoverflow works.